# Error while converting varchar to Decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my table I have a column(Varchar). It contains values like 'abc^1234567^xyz'.
I need to select part of the value and convert it to select the number and convert it to a decimal number and compare this number to a number from another table by joining two tables. 
So far I get error while want to convert it from varchar to decimal.

Here is my error message:
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
Here is my code:

```
SELECT  
    a.Status,
    Cast(SUBSTRING(sourceNatKey, LEN(sourceNatKey)-11,7) As Decimal(18,4)),
    b.caseId
FROM AGREEMENT_STATUS a
INNER JOIN APPLICATION_FACT b
ON 
Cast(SUBSTRING(sourceNatKey, LEN(sourceNatKey)-11,7) As decimal(18,4)) = 
b.caseId
```

Comment: If 2012+, use try_convert() or try_cast().   Rather than throwing an errror, these will return NULL values if the conversion fails.

Comment: Have you tried selecting your substring to see if you've actually got the right part?

Comment: yes, I had to put -10 instead. I get the number part correctly now

Comment: I highly recommend fixing your design. Violating the first normal form of database design will cause you nothing but problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the LIKE operator in the JOIN for such situations.
But if you really have to get a substring from such string ('abc^1234567^xyz'), you could use such construction:

```
 SELECT  
        a.Status,
       Cast(SUBSTRING(sourceNatKey, CHARINDEX('^',sourceNatKey) + 1,CHARINDEX('^',sourceNatKey, CHARINDEX('^',sourceNatKey)+1) - CHARINDEX('^',sourceNatKey) - 1)  As decimal(18,4)),
        b.caseId
    FROM AGREEMENT_STATUS a
    INNER JOIN APPLICATION_FACT b
    ON 
    Cast(SUBSTRING(sourceNatKey, CHARINDEX('^',sourceNatKey) + 1,CHARINDEX('^',sourceNatKey, CHARINDEX('^',sourceNatKey)+1) - CHARINDEX('^',sourceNatKey) - 1)  As decimal(18,4)) = 
    b.caseID
```

Comment: Thank you. this is a better solution. The first one takes ages for my big tables to run, but yours is much more efficient!

Comment: @VBS . . . I am guessing that this can take advantage of an index on `caseId`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this the other way:

```
SELECT  
    a.Status,
    b.caseId
FROM AGREEMENT_STATUS a JOIN
     APPLICATION_FACT af
     ON sourceNatKey LIKE '%^' + CAST(b.caseID as varchar(255)) + '^%'
```

The `caseId` column has the information in your second column, so that doesn't need to be repeated.

Comment: This works, but since I need to run my codes on big tables, it takes ages to run this code. I manipulated Herman's solution and got faster results. Thank you anyway! :-)

Comment: @VBS . . . Interesting.  I'm surprised that it is that much faster.

Answer (score 0):

The code `SUBSTRING(sourceNatKey, LEN(sourceNatKey)-11,7)` will result in `^123456` given the value `abc^1234567^xyz`. This fails because `^` is non-numeric. Change the offset value from the `LEN` call to be `-10` in order to only retrieve the numeric part of your string.

For further information regarding `SUBSTRING`, see [SUBSTRING (Transact-SQL) Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql).

Comment: @VBS Are you certain the data is in the specified format? If any value in the column is not in that format it will fail for the aforementioned reason (but a different character of course).